# Is it possible to display a tooltip only when hovered over a checked radio button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

I want to display the tooltip only when I hover over a checked radio button.
When hovered on the radio button I'm trying to check

```
$(this).is(':checked') == true
```

But the tooltip is displayed only when hovered on "Yes". What am I doing wrong here?.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

```js
$("input[name^='radioBtn']").hover(function () {
if(($(this).is(':checked')) == true){
var text= "Hello";
$(".displayContents").append(text);
}
});
```

```css
.radioHover:hover ~ .displayContents{
    visibility: visible;
  }

.displayContents{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-spacing: 35px; */
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn radioHover" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn radioHover"/><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn radioHover" value="true" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn"/><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use jQuery to achieve your desired goal. It is enough to aim the `:hover` pseudo-class at the `:checked` pseudo-class, in the css. Like this:

```
.radioHover:checked:hover ~ .displayContents {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

For unique content of each radio button, use id `#radioYes` and `#radioNo` with operator `~`.

```js
$("#radioYes ~ .displayContents").text("Hello Yes");
$("#radioNo ~ .displayContents").text("Hello No");
```

```css
.radioHover:checked:hover ~ .displayContents {
    visibility: visible;
}

.displayContents {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-spacing: 35px; */
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn radioHover" /><br />
        <div class="displayContents"></div>
        <span>Yes</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn radioHover" /><br />
        <div class="displayContents"></div>
        <span>No</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you put `radioHover` into name attribute.

Anyway, you should set `radioHover` class on the checked button only, like so:

```js
$("input[name='radioBtn']").hover(function () {
this.classList.toggle("radioHover", this.checked);
if($(this).is(':checked') == true){
var text= "Hello";
$(".displayContents").append(text);
}
});
```

```css
.radioHover:hover ~ .displayContents{
    visibility: visible;
  }

.displayContents{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-spacing: 35px; */
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn"/><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="false" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn"/><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some typos and some misunderstandings. The `radioHover` class was in the `name` field, was missing in the class for the 'no' radio. Additionally, you have 2 different `. displayContents` elements. The way to target the one associated with the radio is via the `.closest(selector).find(selector)` combo. I didn't think you wanted to actually append the same HTML continuously, so I changed that to `.html()`.

Finally, I added the 'change' event in the mix - that way you'll get your value on hover and on click (if checked). Reason being, you are hovering over the element when you click it. Yet the hover didn't update when the state went from not-checked to checked. Now it does

```js
$("input[name='radioBtn']").on('hover, change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('div').find(".displayContents").html('Hello from ' + $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```css
.radioHover:checked:hover~.displayContents {
  visibility: visible;
}

.displayContents {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 350px;
  /* border-spacing: 35px; */
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="yes" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn radioHover" /><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="no" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn radioHover" /><br />
    <div class="displayContents"></div>
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Kinglish your explanation actually made a lot of things clear to me. Appreciate it.